# Blender 2.79 camera moves too early

Tags: animation, camera

So I'm making an animation in blender and the camera moves, The only problem is when I watch the animation the camera doesn't start moving where I have the keyframe set. I have the keyframe set at 35 and the animation ends at 56 frames. The camera starts moving at the very beginning which is not what I want, I want it to start moving at the keyframe. I set the keyframes as locrotscales so what I'm animating would have some movement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the timeline, the dopesheet or the graph window, grab the initial keyframe and move it to the frame where you want the motion to start

Comment: Hello, please share your file (only the camera): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/